# Remove CPT's taxonomy base slug from wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having "Tour" as CPT. In this I'm having Main page, Category page and Detail page.

Main page     - https://www.exapmle.com/tour/

Category Page - https://www.exapmle.com/tour/category-page/

Detail Page   - https://www.exapmle.com/tour/detail-page/

**I need these as Below**

Main page     - https://www.exapmle.com/tour/

Category Page - https://www.exapmle.com/category-page/

Detail Page   - https://www.exapmle.com/detail-page/

Answer (score 0):

When registering your CPT you provided some arguments... One of the arguments is 'rewrite'. You can provide an array of options,like 'slug', 'with_front', 'pages', etc.

Maybe you can try to set the slug to be empty? Or to be '/'?

```
$args = [
    ...
    'rewrite' => ['slug' => '', 'with_front' => false],
    ...
];
register_post_type('your-cpt-slug', $args);
```

I hope it works!